# Writing a server on asynchronous socket

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

After writing the client, I'm trying to write a server using an asynchronous socket. I found the server implementation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx).

I start the server and it will wait for the connection to come in. On the GUI side I will have a button that will connect my server to the client. If there is no client, I want an error message shown on the GUI and it will wait for another button click. And if there is a client, I need both of them to show "Connected" in the GUI and start working.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/) library ? It uses several transport protocols including sockets.

Comment: I just don't have time to learn another library. ;-) Thank you.